# Entity Framework Core 7 - how to disable Identity Insert for table on server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a C# app using EF Core 7 and I am trying to insert a number of rows into a table that has an `identity(1,1)` column as its PK.

I am making a call to `SqlQueryRaw` to turn ON identity insert as follows (with the context):

```
Database.SqlQueryRaw<String>($"SET IDENTITY_INSERT BobTable ON");
```

However, when I try and add the data and call submit it throws an exception that IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF.

I also have `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` set on the entity. I've also tried adding `ValueGeneratedNever()` in `ModelBuilder`, and in SSMS turning identity_insert on in T-SQL before running the code with the same error. Turning it on and doing the insert from SSMS works as expected.

The basic sequence is for is:

```
BeginTransaction
IDENTITY_INSERT ON
SaveChanges()
IDENTITY_INSERT OFF
CommitTransaction
```

Does anyone know why the `IDENTITY INSERT` is being ignored, or do you have a solution for the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As usual, half an hour after asking the question I found a solution.

When the table is not an identity table, I just use normal SaveChanges().

When the table had an identity column, I needed to use CreateDbCommand() on the DBSet to create and execute the SET statements (ON and OFF) with a call to SaveChanges() in between.  This required opening a new connection to the database.